# How to show monthly archive posts?

Tags: categories, archives, date

my custom archives page is :

```
<?php get_header(); 

print ('<div class="row">');
    $archi = wp_get_archives('echo=0');
    $archi = explode( '</li>' , $archi );
    $archi_count = count($archi);
    $count = 1;
    $itemCount = 0;
    foreach( $archi as $link ) {
        $link = str_replace( array( '<li>' , "\n" , "\t" , "\s" ), '' , $link );
        if($count == 1) {
            print('<div class="medium-4 large-4 columns category_list"><ul>');
                $itemCount++;
        }
        if(!empty($link)){  
            $arr = array($link);
            print('<li>' . $arr['0'] . '</li> ');
            $itemCount++;
        }
        else continue;          
        if($count == (ceil($archi_count/3))) {
            print('</ul></div>');
            $count=1;
        }
        else $count++;  
    }
    if ($count != (ceil($archi_count/3)) && $count > 1) // If last column does not have it's 7 items, then close the column
        print('</ul></div>');
print('</div>');

get_footer(); ?>
```

It's showing a list of months archive links such as Apr 2014. When I click it redirects to htttp://www.mysite.com/blog/2014/04. In this page how can I show all the posts those are posted in Apr 2014.? Means in **date.php**..

my date.php

```
<?php
$args = array( ****WHAT ARE THE ARGUMENTS I HAVE TO PASS HERE?****);        
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
archive_row();
endforeach; ?>
```

In function.php

```
function archive_row() { // archive rows archive.php, date.php
    echo '<div class="large-3 medium-3 columns"><a href="' . get_permalink() .'" title="' . get_the_title() . '"><img src="' .archive_thumb() .'" alt="Banner Image x 4" style="width:100%" /></a><a href="' .get_permalink() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '">' . get_the_title() .'</a></div>';        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file date.php in your active theme and use below code, you may need to polish this code as per your requirement:

```
<div id="content" class="post-archive<?php echo $content_class; ?>">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <header class="archive-header">
            <h3 class="archive-title">

                <?php if ( is_day() ) : ?>
                    <?php printf( __( 'Daily Archives: %s' ), '<span>' . get_the_date() . '</span>' ); ?>
                <?php elseif ( is_month() ) : ?>
                    <?php printf( __( 'Monthly Archives: %s' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'fairpixels' ) ) . '</span>' ); ?>
                <?php elseif ( is_year() ) : ?>
                    <?php printf( __( 'Yearly Archives: %s' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'fairpixels' ) ) . '</span>' ); ?>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?php _e( 'Blog Archives' ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </h3>
        </header>

        <div class="archive-postlist">
            <?php $i = 0; ?>                
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php                               
                    $post_class ="";
                    if ( $i % 2 == 1 ){
                        $post_class =" col-last";
                    }                   
                ?>  
                <div class="one-half<?php echo $post_class; ?>">
                    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>   

                                                    <?php       
                                                             if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {  ?>

                                                                    <div class="thumb overlay">
                                                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( ); ?></a>
                                                                    </div>  
                                                    <?php } ?>

                                                    <header class="entry-header">
                                                            <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                                                            <div class="entry-meta">
                                                                    <span class="date">
                                                                            <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
                                                                    </span>


                                                            </div>
                                                    </header>

                                                    <div class="entry-excerpt">
                                                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                                    </div>

                                            </article>
                </div>
                <?php $i++; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <?php //fp_pagination(); ?>         
    <?php else : ?>

        <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found'); ?></h1>
            </header><!-- /entry-header -->

            <div class="entry-content">
                <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'fairpixels' ); ?></p>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </div><!-- /entry-content -->
        </article><!-- /post-0 -->

    <?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- /content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The item worth noting here is the Template Hierarchy of Wordpress. (http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

These templates basically cover 99% of all Wordpress pages ever needed. If you work within the realm of such a template there is no need of generating an own query, Wordpress has already done so and all you have to do is to generate a loop to show the results.

This is a fairly standard archive.php that I use to display archives on my blogs.

```
<?php
    get_header();

    $post = $posts[0]; // Hack. Set $post so that the_date() works. 
    /* If this is a category archive */ if (is_category()) { 
        $title =__(single_cat_title('', false)); 
    /* If this is a tag archive */ } elseif( is_tag() ) { 
        $title =__('Tag: ', "krautgaming")." ".single_tag_title('', false); 
    /* If this is a daily archive */ } elseif (is_day()) { 
        $title =__('Archive for ', "krautgaming").get_the_time(__('F jS, Y', "krautgaming")).__(' | Daily archive page', "krautgaming"); 
    /* If this is a monthly archive */ } elseif (is_month()) { 
        $title =__('Archive for ', "krautgaming").get_the_time(__('F, Y', "krautgaming")).__(' | Monthly archive page', "krautgaming"); 
    /* If this is a yearly archive */ } elseif (is_year()) { 
        $title =__('Archive for ', "krautgaming").get_the_time(__('Y', "krautgaming")).__(' | Yearly archive page', "krautgaming"); 
    /* If this is an author archive */ } elseif (is_author()) { 
        $title =__('Author Archive', "krautgaming"); 
    /* If this is a paged archive */ } elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) { 
        $title =__('Blog Archives', "krautgaming"); 
    /* If this is a channel archive */ } elseif (is_tax('channel')) {
        $title =__('Videos by', "krautgaming")." ".single_tag_title('', false);
    /* If this is a video archive */ } elseif (is_post_type_archive('video')) {
        $title =__('Recent Videos', "krautgaming");
    } else {
        $title =__("Recent Posts", "krautgaming");
    }
?>

<div class="sub_header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">
                <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="center-container container">
    <?php
        if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post();
    ?>
        <!-- Display posts here -->
    <?php
        endwhile; endif;
    ?>
</div>

<?php
    get_footer();
?>
```